# How can I combine 2 tables into a third table SQL without overwriting?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

so i have 3 Sql tables, I run this command

```
INSERT INTO `wp_atkv_EWD_OTP_Customers` (`Customer_ID`,`Customer_Email`,`Customer_Created`) 
SELECT 
    `User_ID`, 
    `Username` , 
    `User_Date_Created` 
FROM `wp_atkv_EWD_FEUP_Users`
```

and it works perfectly fine I want to add data from another table using the same user id but then I run the command below it says duplicate error? Should I not be using insert into? also if i ignore the duplicate it just creates new entries I want them all in the same row

```
INSERT INTO `wp_atkv_EWD_OTP_Customers` (`Customer_ID`,`Customer_Name`) 
SELECT 
    `User_ID`, 
    group_concat(`Field_Value`) 
FROM `wp_atkv_EWD_FEUP_User_Fields` 
GROUP by `User_ID`
```

What Should I do how can I update with the third table?

Comment: Why do you move data around between the tables?

Comment: Well, it has to do with this wordpress plugin reading from a certain table. It seems easier to move the data then to rewrite the plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm expecting a `join`:

```
INSERT INTO wp_atkv_EWD_OTP_Customers (Customer_ID, Customer_Email, Customer_Created, Customer_Name)
    SELECT u.User_ID, u.Username, u.User_Date_Created, uf.vals
    FROM wp_atkv_EWD_FEUP_Users u LEFT JOIN
         (SELECT User_ID, group_concat(Field_Value) as vals 
          FROM wp_atkv_EWD_FEUP_User_Fields
          GROUP by User_ID
         ) uf
         ON u.user_id = uf.user_id;
```

Alternatively, you might want an `update`:

```
update wp_atkv_EWD_OTP_Customers c join
       (select `User_ID`, group_concat(`Field_Value`) as vals
        from `wp_atkv_EWD_FEUP_User_Fields` 
        group by `User_ID`
       ) uf
       on c.customer_id_id = cf.user_id
    set Customer_Name = uf.vals;
```

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly, if you have time this is kindod a noob question but what does the u. that you put before the variables mean? Also did it have to be a left join? or could it have been a different one used?

Comment: @MarkKetchumManzarescu . . . Those are qualified column names.  They show where the column comes from.